# Adding employeeId on login with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I need to store employeeId in session whenever user logs in. I can't do it in /login POST method because of Spring Security intercepting POST /login endpoint.   What is the way to add additional user details to session in that case? Thank you!

Comment: You can configure an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` that will get called after authentication has completed successfully. This has an `onAuthenticationSuccess` method that gets an `HttpServletRequest`, an `HttpServletResponse` and an `Authentication` as parameters, to which you can add the required information.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter which will be called on /login POST. There you can do the session storing functionalities.

See the JwtAuthenticationFilter class usage in the following https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java.